# Telegram Bot API: "username" field is missing

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot, php-telegram-bot

I want to read user names from receiving updates however but I face an special issue.

For some users, `$message['from']['username']` contains a Telegram User Name however for some users this parameter is not defined.

How can I reliably receive user names ( get `username` field), using Telegram Bot API?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's not mandatory to have a username, so there are users with no username.

Answer (score 1):

Simply use this code:

```
if(!$username){
$parameters = array("chat_id" => $chatId, "text" => "Set a username to use this bot!\nSettings > Username");
}
```

When a user have no username it can't use the bot.